# div with min height en expanding with content

Tags: html, css, height

I have a div that has a min-height of 70%.  And in that div I have a div where I place my content.
When the content is above 70% my div grows and puts the footer further down. And that is exactly what I want. The only problem I have is that when the div where I place my content  is empty the div is empty. I want this div with or without content 100% full and still be able to expand if the content goes above 100%. But how? It needs to be 100% height for 900px height screens and 600px height screens and smaller.

The problems are the following two divs:

```
    #wrapper
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;

}

#content
{
margin-left: 50%;
min-height: 100%;
background-color: yellow;

}
```

html:

```
  <div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
So this is the div that needs to be able to expand. And it needs to be 100% height, even if its not 100% filled like now or empty 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `&nbsp;` in your empty div

Comment: I added around 20 &nbsp; tags, and still its not 100%, so not really what I am looking for, but thanks for the idea. And maybe what I want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I know what I need to do, in the second div I need to add height: 100vh;